# ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer :: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation

I am working on multi class segmentation of skin tissues, i have a list of 1500 labels, each one classified into 4 classes [0,1,2,3] , my aim is to segment each label class separately.When i try to train my model my model i got this error . Is the way i am defining my model wrong ?, kindly please suggest me.

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 1 but received input with shape (None, 224, 224, 1, 3)
```

I have loaded the set of labels and corresponding classes associated with labels through this approach

```
imagePath = "/home/SKIN_TISSUE/TISSUE_SET_1500/"

    x_train = []
    y_train = []
    for index, row in tqdm(x_train_list.iterrows(), total=x_train_list.shape[0]):
        try:
            loadedImage = plt.imread(imagePath + str(row[0]) + ".jpg")
            x_train.append(loadedImage)
            y_train.append(row[1])
        except:
            # Try with .png file format if images are not properly loaded
            try:
                loadedImage = plt.imread(imagePath + str(row[0]) + ".png")
                x_train.append(loadedImage)
                y_train.append(row[1])
            except:
                # Print file names whenever it is impossible to load image files
                print(imagePath + str(row[0]))

x_test = []
y_test = []
for index, row in tqdm(x_test_list.iterrows(), total=x_test_list.shape[0]):
    try:
        loadedImage = plt.imread(imagePath + str(row[0]) + ".jpg")
        x_test.append(loadedImage)
        y_test.append(row[1])
    except:
        # Try with .png file format if images are not properly loaded
        try:
            loadedImage = plt.imread(imagePath + str(row[0]) + ".png")
            x_test.append(loadedImage)
            y_test.append(row[1])
        except:
            # Print file names whenever it is impossible to load image files
            print(imagePath + str(row[0]))
```

and i have loaded the class files through this method

```
# Path to superpixels class files
classes_file = "/home/DEV/SKIN_TISSUE/TISSUE_1500_CLASSES.csv"
concatenated_data= pd.read_csv(classes_file, header=None)

# Instances with targets
targets = concatenated_data[1].tolist()

# Split data according to their classes
class_0 = concatenated_data[concatenated_data[1] == 0]
class_1 = concatenated_data[concatenated_data[1] == 1]
class_2 = concatenated_data[concatenated_data[1] == 2]
class_3 = concatenated_data[concatenated_data[1] == 3]

# Holdout split train/test set (Other options are k-folds or leave-one-out)
split_proportion = 0.9

split_size_0 = int(len(class_0)*split_proportion)
split_size_1 = int(len(class_1)*split_proportion)
split_size_2 = int(len(class_2)*split_proportion)
split_size_3 = int(len(class_3)*split_proportion)

new_class_0_train = np.random.choice(len(class_0), split_size_0, replace=False)
new_class_0_train = class_0.iloc[new_class_0_train]
new_class_0_test = ~class_0.iloc[:][0].isin(new_class_0_train.iloc[:][0])
new_class_0_test = class_0[new_class_0_test]

new_class_1_train = np.random.choice(len(class_1), split_size_1, replace=False)
new_class_1_train = class_1.iloc[new_class_1_train]
new_class_1_test = ~class_1.iloc[:][0].isin(new_class_1_train.iloc[:][0])
new_class_1_test = class_1[new_class_1_test]

new_class_2_train = np.random.choice(len(class_2), split_size_2, replace=False)
new_class_2_train = class_2.iloc[new_class_2_train]
new_class_2_test = ~class_2.iloc[:][0].isin(new_class_2_train.iloc[:][0])
new_class_2_test = class_2[new_class_2_test]

new_class_3_train = np.random.choice(len(class_3), split_size_3, replace=False)
new_class_3_train = class_3.iloc[new_class_3_train]
new_class_3_test = ~class_3.iloc[:][0].isin(new_class_3_train.iloc[:][0])
new_class_3_test = class_3[new_class_3_test]

x_train_list = pd.concat(
    [new_class_0_train, new_class_1_train, new_class_2_train, new_class_3_train])
x_test_list = pd.concat(
    [new_class_0_test, new_class_1_test, new_class_2_test, new_class_3_test])
```

Model is defined as follows :

```
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
#from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
#K.set_image_data_format('channels_first')
class_weights = class_weight.compute_sample_weight('balanced', y_train)

print("Class weights are :", class_weights)

IMG_HEIGHT = 224
IMG_WIDTH  = 224
IMG_CHANNELS = 1

### Defining the model

def get_model():
        return multi_unet_model(n_classes=4, IMG_HEIGHT=IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH=IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS=IMG_CHANNELS)
    
model = get_model()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
#model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='focal_loss', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=16, verbose=1,epochs=50,
                    #class_weight = class_weights,
                    validation_data=(x_test,y_test),shuffle=False)
```

Model summary output is :

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 224, 224, 1) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)                 (None, 224, 224, 16) 160         input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)               (None, 224, 224, 16) 0           conv2d[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)               (None, 224, 224, 16) 2320        dropout[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D)    (None, 112, 112, 16) 0           conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)               (None, 112, 112, 32) 4640        max_pooling2d[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 112, 112, 32) 0           conv2d_2[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)               (None, 112, 112, 32) 9248        dropout_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 56, 56, 32)   0           conv2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)               (None, 56, 56, 64)   18496       max_pooling2d_1[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 56, 56, 64)   0           conv2d_4[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)               (None, 56, 56, 64)   36928       dropout_2[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 28, 28, 64)   0           conv2d_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)               (None, 28, 28, 128)  73856       max_pooling2d_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)             (None, 28, 28, 128)  0           conv2d_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)               (None, 28, 28, 128)  147584      dropout_3[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 14, 14, 128)  0           conv2d_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)               (None, 14, 14, 256)  295168      max_pooling2d_3[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)             (None, 14, 14, 256)  0           conv2d_8[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)               (None, 14, 14, 256)  590080      dropout_4[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose (Conv2DTranspo (None, 28, 28, 128)  131200      conv2d_9[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate (Concatenate)       (None, 28, 28, 256)  0           conv2d_transpose[0][0]           
                                                                 conv2d_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)              (None, 28, 28, 128)  295040      concatenate[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)             (None, 28, 28, 128)  0           conv2d_10[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)              (None, 28, 28, 128)  147584      dropout_5[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_1 (Conv2DTrans (None, 56, 56, 64)   32832       conv2d_11[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 56, 56, 128)  0           conv2d_transpose_1[0][0]         
                                                                 conv2d_5[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)              (None, 56, 56, 64)   73792       concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)             (None, 56, 56, 64)   0           conv2d_12[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)              (None, 56, 56, 64)   36928       dropout_6[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTrans (None, 112, 112, 32) 8224        conv2d_13[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_2 (Concatenate)     (None, 112, 112, 64) 0           conv2d_transpose_2[0][0]         
                                                                 conv2d_3[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_14 (Conv2D)              (None, 112, 112, 32) 18464       concatenate_2[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_7 (Dropout)             (None, 112, 112, 32) 0           conv2d_14[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_15 (Conv2D)              (None, 112, 112, 32) 9248        dropout_7[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_3 (Conv2DTrans (None, 224, 224, 16) 2064        conv2d_15[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_3 (Concatenate)     (None, 224, 224, 32) 0           conv2d_transpose_3[0][0]         
                                                                 conv2d_1[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_16 (Conv2D)              (None, 224, 224, 16) 4624        concatenate_3[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_8 (Dropout)             (None, 224, 224, 16) 0           conv2d_16[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_17 (Conv2D)              (None, 224, 224, 16) 2320        dropout_8[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_18 (Conv2D)              (None, 224, 224, 4)  68          conv2d_17[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,940,868
Trainable params: 1,940,868
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: your x_train seems to have shape (n_sample, 224, 224, 1, 3)... how did u obtain them?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani, I have updated my question, please review it.

Comment: it seems x_train/x_test are passed in list format... if your try x_train = np.concatenate(x_train)... what is x_train.shape ?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Out[34]: (301728, 224, 1, 3)

Comment: ok, but are you sure your images have only one channel?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani, my images have only 1 channel. 100%  sure

Comment: so loadedImage obtained from plt.imread(...) must return an array (224,224) as reported here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html, do u confirm?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani loadedImage returns an array of (224,224)

Comment: ok, but this is not consistent with a final list/array of shape (n_sample, 224, 224, 1, 3)

Comment: @MarcoCerliani, yes , how should i proceed in my scenario i have 1500 labels and each label image belongs to a class [0,1,2,3] and i would like to train my labels and test it on random image to segment all four skin tissue classes

Comment: Image should be of shape (n_sample,height, width, channels) but in this you have more than 3 parameters. There should be consistency in the image shape. Convert all the images to grey scale. Use image shape as (301728, 224, 1). Your Conv2D layer looks like `Conv2D( ......input_shape = (224, 224, 1))`.